# RSA token Authentication in ASP application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, two-factor-authentication

Does anyone have experience with how you can programatically use RSA two factor authentication (pin+token)?
I dont think the IIS agent Will solve my problem it doesnt seem to have an API that wraps the functionality.
Is there like any SOAP or REST service available in RSA server?
I am looking for to authenticate pin + token onside the MVC (C#) application so not on IIS level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to use radius on the RSA server.
Here is an excellent library for it in C#
https://github.com/frontporch/Radius.NET